# Rstudio own Method/Function minihelp

Tags: r, autocomplete, rstudio

If I write a method or function, how can i get that "minihelp" (whose special term I dont know) which is shown while writing a function?
E.g. for "plot" it exists; Type

```
>plot([TAB]
```

then the following shows in a kind of "Tooltip"

```
x= 
y=
... =
```

and if you choose for example "x", then after a second the following tooltip shows:

```
x   
the coordinates of points in the plot. Alternatively, a single plotting 
structure, function or any R object with a plot method can be provided.
```

Some info but not crucial to the problem: I am working with Rstudio and writing multiple S4 generics/methods for the class ExpressionSet. 
Sadly I can't manage to find a cool google keyword, so I hope you can help me out!

---

Edith:
The following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565526/is-it-possible-to-get-rstudio-to-show-function-arguments-and-descriptions-for-cu) is about the same as mine but i have still the ongoing problem that I *already wrote* a package, every function is documented with roxygen, I followed hadleys descriptions. Nevertheless, the tooltips do not show up.

In the linked question it is said that "help files must be generated" - which I assume are generated as ?myS4Method is showing the appropriate help pages. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be a duplicate yes - but even by creating a package it does not work..

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you are looking for comes from the way RStudio parses the documentation of packages. If you create a package, you can add [Roxygen](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html) comments to your functions or classes. These comments are then parsed when you create the package into documentation files that you see as the help for a function.

If you run the command `?plot` you will see a list of Arguments. These are the parameters that can be passed to the function and that is what the tooltip in RStudio is telling you about.

To get RStudio to give you info about the functions you are using, you should bundle your S4 classes into a package ([Hadley Wickham's tutorial](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#man-s4)) and make sure they are correctly documented. RStudio will take care of the rest.

Comment: So, I already use the Roxygen comments - the documentation devtools::document() runs without warning nor error. 
?"myfunction" works fine, all Arguments are described correctly there. 

Nevertheless, the tooltip does not show - do I miss some part?

Comment: Are you loading the function from a package? See Hadley's comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565526/is-it-possible-to-get-rstudio-to-show-function-arguments-and-descriptions-for-cu) question.

Comment: yep I am :( There must be something I oversee...