# How can I make the glht function print the degrees of freedom used?

Tags: r, lme4, summary

My question is a bit more general, and was already asked here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554505/how-can-i-see-all-of-the-valid-options-for-an-argument-in-an-r-function). However, there seems to be no general solution. Therefore, I try to use an example. What is an efficient way to proceed to get the summary function applied to a glht object print the degrees of freedom used by the glht to compute the p-values? I think I should add an argument to the summary function, but which one?

Comment: Can you give a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way to find the possible arguments is to look into the function code. The summary function returns a list object, what governs what's printed is the `print()` function, so that's what we want to analize.

But `print()` is a *generic function*, this is an *Object Oriented Programming* that basically means "a function that has different methods for each type of object it can receive". Running the code `print` gets us:

```
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
```

So we can't access the specific method of `print()` that it's used with a glht summary. To do that, we can either use debugging, or use the `sloop` package:

```
sloop::s3_methods_generic('print')

# A tibble: 403 × 4
   generic class       visible source             
   <chr>   <chr>       <lgl>   <chr>              
 1 print   aareg       FALSE   registered S3method
 2 print   abbrev      FALSE   registered S3method
 3 print   acf         FALSE   registered S3method
 4 print   all_vars    FALSE   registered S3method
 5 print   anova       FALSE   registered S3method
 6 print   Anova       FALSE   registered S3method
 7 print   anova.loglm FALSE   registered S3method
 8 print   any_vars    FALSE   registered S3method
 9 print   aov         FALSE   registered S3method
10 print   aovlist     FALSE   registered S3method
# ℹ 393 more rows
```

These are all the methods that you have installed for `print()`. Now select the ones that have something to do with glht:

```
sloop::s3_methods_generic('print') |> filter(grepl('glht', class))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  generic class        visible source             
  <chr>   <chr>        <lgl>   <chr>              
1 print   confint.glht FALSE   registered S3method
2 print   glht         FALSE   registered S3method
3 print   summary.glht FALSE   registered S3method
```

Thus, we want the code for the method `print.summary.glht()` (this is the default syntax for methods, *function.class*):

```
sloop::s3_get_method('print.summary.glht')

function (x, digits = max(3, getOption("digits") - 3), ...) 
{
    cat("\n\t", "Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses\n\n")
    if (!is.null(x$type))
... #I omitted the rest of the function
```

Now we can see that the arguments are `x`, `digits` (that are globally defined), and `...` (which aren't used anywhere in the method). So, in conclusion, there isn't an argument to display the degrees of freedom.

But, now that you have access to the function's code, you can alter it yourself, adding `cat("Degrees of Freedom: ", x$df, "\n")` near the end, and saving it with the same name:

```
print.summary.glht <- function (x, digits = max(3, getOption("digits") - 3), ...){
  cat("\n\t", "Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses\n\n")
  if (!is.null(x$type)) 
    cat("Multiple Comparisons of Means:", x$type, "Contrasts\n\n\n")
  call <- if (isS4(x$model)) 
    x$model@call
  else x$model$call
  if (!is.null(call)) {
    cat("Fit: ")
    print(call)
    cat("\n")
  }
  pq <- x$test
  mtests <- cbind(pq$coefficients, pq$sigma, pq$tstat, pq$pvalues)
  error <- attr(pq$pvalues, "error")
  pname <- switch(x$alternative, less = paste("Pr(<", ifelse(x$df == 
                                                               0, "z", "t"), ")", sep = ""), greater = paste("Pr(>", 
                                                                                                             ifelse(x$df == 0, "z", "t"), ")", sep = ""), two.sided = paste("Pr(>|", 
                                                                                                                                                                            ifelse(x$df == 0, "z", "t"), "|)", sep = ""))
  colnames(mtests) <- c("Estimate", "Std. Error", ifelse(x$df == 
                                                           0, "z value", "t value"), pname)
  type <- pq$type
  if (!is.null(error) && error > .Machine$double.eps) {
    sig <- which.min(abs(1/error - (10^(1:10))))
    sig <- 1/(10^sig)
  }
  else {
    sig <- .Machine$double.eps
  }
  cat("Linear Hypotheses:\n")
  alt <- switch(x$alternative, two.sided = "==", less = ">=", 
                greater = "<=")
  rownames(mtests) <- paste(rownames(mtests), alt, x$rhs)
  printCoefmat(mtests, digits = digits, has.Pvalue = TRUE, 
               P.values = TRUE, eps.Pvalue = sig)
  cat("Degrees of Freedom: ", x$df, "\n") #our new line
  switch(type, univariate = cat("(Univariate p values reported)"), 
         `single-step` = cat("(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)"), 
         Shaffer = cat("(Adjusted p values reported -- Shaffer method)"), 
         Westfall = cat("(Adjusted p values reported -- Westfall method)"), 
         cat("(Adjusted p values reported --", type, "method)"))
  cat("\n\n")
  invisible(x)
}
```

**Example of outcome:**

```
lmod <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
K <- diag(length(coef(lmod)))[-1,]
rownames(K) <- names(coef(lmod))[-1]
glht(lmod, linfct = K) |> summary() |> print()

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)

Linear Hypotheses:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
Agriculture == 0      -0.17211    0.07030  -2.448   0.0793 .  
Examination == 0      -0.25801    0.25388  -1.016   0.7847    
Education == 0        -0.87094    0.18303  -4.758   <0.001 ***
Catholic == 0          0.10412    0.03526   2.953   0.0233 *  
Infant.Mortality == 0  1.07705    0.38172   2.822   0.0325 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Degrees of Freedom:  41 #our new line
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Value section of `?glht` it says that `df` is a component of the output of `glht` so if `g` is a `glht` object, i.e. the output of `glht`, then the following shows the summary and the degrees of freedom.  You can just issue the two lines or wrap it in a function if you like.

```
summary(g)
g$df
```

This also works since `summary.glht` maintains the `df` component:

```
s <- summary(g)
s
s$df
```

Comment: thanks! this prints a 0 for an 'lmer' object. I thought it was wrong, but it is correct since: "glht extracts the number of degrees of freedom for models of class lm (via modelparm) and the exact multivariate t distribution is evaluated. For all other models, results rely on the normal approximation." And the normal approximation has no df... For an 'lm' object it prints the number of degrees of freedom as you say.

Comment: To print all in one line of code you can do `print(summary(g)); cat('Degrees of Freedom:', g$df)`